# Как сделать аргумент master необязательным в функции инициации виджета tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Вопрос вроде бы простой, но я не знаю, как его решить.

Есть код:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    global root

    def __init__(self, master=root):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()


root = MainWindow()
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
button1 = MyButton()
button2 = MyButton(master=frame1)
root.mainloop()
```

Хочу, чтобы работали оба варианта при вызове функции `__init__` в классе MyButton:

1. Если аргумент master не указан, то используется значение этого аргумента по умолчанию master=root

`button1 = MyButton()`

2. Если указано значение аргумента master, то оно используется вместо значения по умолчанию

`button2 = MyButton(master=frame1)`

Происходит ошибка

> NameError: name 'root' is not defined

в строке `def __init__(self, master=root):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите `None` как параметр по-умолчанию. При передаче `None` в качестве родительского элемента tkinter считает родительским главное окно (первый созданный объект `Tk`, если он существует, или создает новый). Детали реализации можно посмотреть в [`tkinter/__init__.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py) (вкратце, первый созданный объект `Tk` записывается в глобальную переменную `_default_root`, потом это значение используется как родитель по умолчанию). Для передачи параметров в родительский класс можно использовать функцию `super()`, в этом случае не нужно будет передавать `self`:

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class MyButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()


root = MainWindow()
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack()
button1 = MyButton()
button2 = MyButton(master=frame1)
root.mainloop()
```